# I need to get the value of the text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-mvc

I am trying to get the value of the input type text that is in a loop which is populating from JavaScript which is like :

```
test.innerHTML += "<span class=egclass'><span class='egclass2'><input type='text' id='idText' name='textName' value='${eController.userName["+i+"]}' /></span>
```

I am able to send the entered text values to the backend controller but not able to get the values by : document.getElementsByName[i].value;

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `document.getElementById` instead of `document.getElementsByName`?

Comment: Did you try `document.getElementsByName("textName")[i].value`?

Comment: I tried using getElementById as well. But its not working. I am getting null. @ThePloki

Comment: Yes that's an integer from a loop iteration @user3917611

Comment: Thanks a lot @user3917611. Your suggestion worked out. :)

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you posted more of the code, because we're slightly confused about the context, but I'll give it a shot:

Try changing to this:

```
test.innerHTML += "<span class=egclass'><span class='egclass2'><input type='text' id='idText_"+i+"' name='textName' value='${eController.userName["+i+"]}' /></span>
```

Then you should be able to access it with `document.getElementById('idText_'+i).value`

Hope it helps.

Edit: Changed `.innerHTML` to `.value`. Also, as Cobus mentioned in the comments, its worth pointing out that the reason this fixes the problem is because all of the inputs will now have unique ID's.

Comment: "document.getElementsByName("textName")[i].value" works perfectly fine  @ThePloki . Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I will give a try like mentioned above as well.

Comment: Just to explain this a little better, the problem is that the original code creates multiple inputs with the same ID. Only the first of those will be accessible. This answer fixes the issue by creating unique IDs.

Comment: Also @Rnga if you like the answer so much, please accept it.